# Marshal String to and from C in C#

Tags: c#, openssl, interop

Ok, so there are a bunch of questions with an almost identical title. I've been through them and nothing works. I am trying to call a native method from the OpenSSL library.

```
char *ERR_error_string(unsigned long e, char *buf);
```

https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/ERR_error_string

Currently, my function looks like:

```
[DllImport(DLLNAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static StringBuilder ERR_error_string(ulong e, StringBuilder buf);
```

When calling the function I get:

> The target process exited with code 0 while evaluating the function '...GetErrorString'.

It might be worth noting I am trying this in the watch window of VS 2019.

Comment: How did you come up with a  C `char` pointer equals to a .net `StringBuilder` ?

Comment: Try to use `ERR_error_string_n` instead and make sure that your `StringBuilder` buffer is at least as the passed size, and also make sure that your conventions match.

Comment: @Franck string builder is the closest representation of a mutable string there is in c#. If it were 'const char *' then I would have used string...